# split string by one of 2 delimiters depending on what is contained in string

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can explode a string by either one of 2 delimters as the string I want to split can contain either a comma ',' or a hyphen '-'.

Below code works for the ',' but can't get the '-' and ',' to work at the same time.

Any advise?

```
   // first possible string 
$string = "hello, you";
// second possible string 
$string = "hello- you";

//explode function
         list($part1, $part2) = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: I would be curious why you want to use a string like this. Will you need to add another deliminator in the future? Do you have control of the format of the string? For what you have, you are going to have to look at the string to determine whether each deliminator exists and then based upon that check us the appropriate deliminator.

Comment: Actually I'm using an the Google API for places. The city and country places in the API are sometimes delimited by a comma and sometimes by a hyphen, so I need to be able to use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `explode` successively to the string and then the resultant array:

```
$string = "hello, you - sir";
$temp = explode('-', $string);
$result = array();
foreach ($temp as $piece) {
    $result = array_merge($result, explode(',', $piece));
}
```

and `$result` will contain what you are looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] =>  you 
    [2] =>  sir
)
```

Comment: that doesn't do the job for me for some reason.

Comment: @mush yeah, I had to edit it a few iterations. Try now.

Comment: I get this error: <br /><b>Warning</b>:  ucfirst() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: The `ucfirst` function does not appear in the code I answered with. Are you sending `$result` into it?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I didn't input the right index key into my output causing the error. It works perfectly now. I'd love to learn more about what the code does exactly. I can follow up till $result = array() and can see that the line that follows is a loop... Could you explain the reasoning/thought behind the  array, loop and merge part of the code? Thnx.

Comment: `explode` returns an array, so we need to loop through each element of that array (each is a string) and break them up with the 2nd delimiter. Don't forget to upvote if this answer helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$arr = preg_split('/[,-]/', $string);
```

This has the advantage over the `strtok` and recursive `explode` answers by doing all of the looping in C code (so, should be much faster) and allows for the split to be a regular expression, which would be handy if you wanted to also trim the spaces between words:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s*[,-]\s*/', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "abc,def-g,h,i-lm";

$arr = [strtok($string, ',-')];
while (false !== $token = strtok(',-')) {
    $arr[] = $token;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aCFjU).

Answer (score 0):

Strtok()  will work within the for loop for different delimiters